# If- satement and loops in an object arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm doing a school project where I simulate a simple banking system where the user creates the account and can put a deposit, transfer money and delete accounts.

The method transaction should go through the arraylist, find the first account and the second account and transfer money but it jumps the code and says the account cannot be found. How is it possible to fix this problem

The code down below shows what happens in the method

```
public boolean transaction(String accountNumber, String newAccountNumber, double amount){
    for(int i = 0; i < bList.size(); i++){
        if(bList.get(i).getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber)&& bList.get(i).getAccountNumber().equals(newAccountNumber)){
            bList.get(i).deposit(-amount);
            deposit(newAccountNumber, amount);
            return true;
        }
        else if(bList.get(i).getBalance()< amount){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Du har inte tillräckligt med pengar");
            return false;
        }
        else if(!bList.get(i).getAccountNumber().equals(newAccountNumber) && bList.get(i).getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Kontot finns inte ");
            return false;
        }
        else if(!bList.get(i).getAccountNumber().equals(newAccountNumber)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "kontot finns inte");
            return false;
        }
        else if(!bList.get(i).getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Kontot finns inte");
            return false;
        }


    }
    return false;
}
```

The first if-statement should check if both accounts exsist and transfer money from the account that has money to the account that the user has selected but it skips the if-statement and says there is no account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(bList.get(i).getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber)&& bList.get(i).getAccountNumber().equals(newAccountNumber))
```

You are checking if the same account has two different account numbers - `accountNumber` and `newAccountNumber`. This can never be true.

You must locate two accounts, one having the first account number and the other having the second account number.

The naive approach to do it is with a nested for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < bList.size(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < bList.size(); j++){
        if(bList.get(i).getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber) && bList.get(j).getAccountNumber().equals(newAccountNumber)) {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

but that would take `O(n^2)` time. It would be more efficient to store the accounts in a `HashMap` where the account ID is the key and the account is the value.

Comment: I tried cheking with two different it-satements but It gave me the same answere

Comment: Tried doing a nestled for loop but it still gave me the same answer

Comment: @GI88Z In that case, at least one of the accounts you are looking for is not in the List.

Comment: The weird thing is that when I've added 2 accounts int the list and it doen's recognize them

Answer (score 0):

```
if(bList.get(i).getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber)&& bList.get(i).getAccountNumber().equals(newAccountNumber))
```

You are checking the same element for both cases here (both position `i`). The **accountnumber** is probably never `accountNumber` and `newAccountNumber` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

As @eran wrote, you have an obvious error checking if the account has both the accountNumber and newAccountNumber which will of course only be true if you transact to and from the same account .

I think if you refactor the code a bit it would be simpler to debug your error:

```
public boolean transaction(String accountNumber, String newAccountNumber, double amount){
    Account fromAccount = getAccount(accountNumber);
    Account toAccount = getAccount(newAccountNumber);

    if (fromAccount == null || toAccount == null ) {
            // At least one of the accounts is missing
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Kontot finns inte ");
            return false;
    } else if (fromAccount.getBalance() < amount) {
           // Not enough funds
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Du har inte tillräckligt med pengar");
            return false;
    } else {
            fromAccount.deposit(-amount);
            deposit(newAccountNumber, amount);
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public Account getAccount(String accountNumber) {
    for (int i = 0; i < bList.size(); i++){
        if(bList.get(i).getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber) {
            return bList.get(i);
        }
     }
     return null; // No account matches
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your search logic isn't right you are checking the same account object if it has two account numbers.

You can search arraylist of account objects for specific account number using nested for each:

```
for(Account account : bList) {
    for(Account newaccount : bList) {
        if(account.getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber) && newaccount.getAccountNumber().equals(newAccountNumber)){
            //account matches
        }
    }
}
```